# Is it possible to itetrate through an object array dynamically and assign the text and value field to dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have an object array for one of the drop down to be binded as follows

```
[
{CategoryId: 1, CategoryName: 'Collision'},
{CategoryId: 2, CategoryName: 'Groundig'}
]
```

I am able to bind it to dropdown with following code

```
function bindDropDown(data, dropDown, defaultText) {
   var items = "";
   items += "<option value=-1>Select " + defaultText + "</option>";
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
      items += "<option value=\"" + item.CategoryId + "\">" + item.CategoryName + "</option>";
    });
   $(dropDown).html(items);
 }
```

I would like to reuse it so that I can use the same for a different drop down where I will get different options like

```
[
{SubCategoryId: 1, SubCategoryName: 'Collision'},
{SubCategoryId: 2, SubCategoryName: 'Groundig'}
]
```

I am trying to assign the value and text dynamically with out hardcode, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object.values if you do not know or need to know the key names

Also if you do not use jQuery to create the options, I suggest you use template literals to create them. Much more readable

```js
const data = {
  Data: [
    { CategoryId: 1, CategoryName: 'Collision' },
    { CategoryId: 2, CategoryName: 'Groundig' }
  ]
}

const data2 = {
  Data: [
    { SubCategoryId: 1, SubCategoryName: 'Collision2' },
    { SubCategoryId: 2, SubCategoryName: 'Groundig2' }
  ]
}

function bindDropDown(data, dropDown, defaultText) {
  let items = [`<option value="-1" selected>Select ${defaultText}</option>`,
    ...data.Data.map(item => `<option value="${Object.values(item)[0]}">${Object.values(item)[1]}</option>`)]
  $(dropDown).html(items.join(""));
}

bindDropDown(data, "#categories", "Please select");
bindDropDown(data2, "#subcategories", "Please select");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="" id="categories"></select>
<select name="" id="subcategories"></select>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a ton mplungjan

Comment: Can I set the first value as selected by default? I tried this `$(dropDown).val("-1");` didn't worked

Comment: They are already, but now I added `selected` to the first option: `let items = [\`<option value="-1" selected>`

Comment: hmm I added that too but didn't worked let me see what is going wrong

Comment: Worked in both cases for me in Chrome

Comment: ha got it I had a function where it is clearing all the form controls

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `id` and `value` of the select dynamic. I have made use of default value for the arguments aswell.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const data = {
  Data: [
    { CategoryId: 1, CategoryName: 'Collision' },
    { CategoryId: 2, CategoryName: 'Groundig' }
  ]
}

const data2 = {
  Data: [
    { SubCategoryId: 1, SubCategoryName: 'Collision2' },
    { SubCategoryId: 2, SubCategoryName: 'Groundig' }
  ]
}

function bindDropDown(data, dropDown, defaultText, idKey="CategoryId", nameKey="CategoryName") {
  var items = "";
  items += "<option value=-1>Select " + defaultText + "</option>";
  $.each(data.Data, function (i, item) {
    items += "<option value=\"" + item[idKey] + "\">" + item[nameKey] + "</option>";
  });
  $(dropDown).html(items);
}

bindDropDown(data, "#my-select", "please-select");
bindDropDown(data2, "#my-select-2", "please-select", "SubCategoryId", "SubCategoryName");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="" id="my-select"></select>
<select name="" id="my-select-2"></select>
```

Comment: I had that idea in mind but is there other way with out passing them?

Comment: @Developer Yes we have. We need to have a unique logic to identify `id` and `name`. Can we generalize the nodes with key having `Id` as id and havibg `Name` as the name?